# vbs using .Read ( ) with a variable not an interger

Tags: vbscript

I have a problem in that I need to read a specified quantity of characters from a text file, but the specified quantity varies so I cannot use a constant EG:

```
variable = WhateverIsSpecified

strText = objFile.Read (variable)    ' 1 ~ n+1

objOutfile.write strText
```

NOT

```
strText = objFile.Read (n)           ' n = any constant (interger)
```

When using the first way, the output is blank (no characters in the output file)

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

*These are the main snippets in a bit longer code*

```
Set file1 = fso.OpenTextFile(file)

Do Until file1.AtEndOfStream 
    line = file1.ReadLine

    If (Instr(line,"/_N_") =1) then
        line0 = replace(line, "/", "%")                                     
        filename = file1.Readline
        filename = Left(filename, len(filename)-3) & "arc"
        Set objOutFile = fso.CreateTextFile(destfolder & "\" & filename)
        For i = 1 to 5
            line = file1.Readline
        next
        nBytes = line      'this line contains the quantity needed to be read eg 1234

        Do until Instr(line,"\") > 0
            line = file1.ReadLine
        Loop


        StrData = ObjFile.Read (nBytes)
        objOutFile.Write StrData
        objOutFile.close
    End if
Loop

WScript.quit
```

Comment: Can you show us all your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own stupid error,

```
StrData = ObjFile.Read (nBytes)
```

*should be*

```
StrData = file1.Read (nBytes)
```

Comment: `Option Explicit` would catch situations like this :)